# Customtkinter Textbox ignores indexing

Tags: dataframe, indexing, textbox, customtkinter

I wonder if someone could please help.
I am trying to iterate through a dataframe in order to populate a textbox with the values.
In a for loop I modify the index values for each row. For now I am trying to output the first column as a column in the textbox but the values print in a line. I have simplified the code to show the issue, the dataframe is much larger. Code below:

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import pandas as pd

technologies = ({
    'Courses':["Spark","PySpark","Hadoop","Python","pandas","Oracle","Java"],
    'Fee' :[20000,25000,26000,22000,24000,21000,22000],
    'Duration':['30day', '40days' ,'35days', '40days', '60days', '50days', '55days']
                })

df = pd.DataFrame(technologies)

class Window(ctk.CTkToplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("1000x600")

        self.textbox = ctk.CTkTextbox(master=self, width=1000, height=600, corner_radius=0)
        self.textbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")


class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Creditor reports")

        self.toplevel_window = None
        self.Window = None

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.get_button = ctk.CTkButton(self, width=40, text="get", command=self.button_callback)
        self.get_button.grid(row=5, column=3, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="n", rowspan=1)
       
    def button_callback(self):
        if self.toplevel_window is None or not self.toplevel_window.winfo_exists():
            self.toplevel_window = Window(self)
        else:
            self.toplevel_window.focus()
        output_listing(self)


def output_listing(self):
    for i in range(len(df)):
        index_val = str(i) + '.0'
        print(index_val)
        self.toplevel_window.textbox.insert(index_val, df.iloc[i, 0])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

The output in the textbox is:

```
PySparkSparkHadoopPythonpandasOracleJava
```

The print statement outputs:

```
0.0
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
6.0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I hope it's just a silly oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Upstairs add import customtkinter

def output_listing(self):
    for i in range(len(df)):
        self.toplevel_window.textbox.insert(customtkinter.END, df.iloc[i, 0] + "\n")
```

Comment: It seems you will need to import the full customtkinter library as well as the variable you already have declared, for this to work.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**